# emacs efficient buffer switching across dual monitors

Tags: emacs

just switched from single to dual monitors

have managed to utilise both screens with emacs by using `C-x 5 f` to open a file in a buffer in a new frame, i can drag that frame on to the 2nd monitor and enjoy my extra real-estate

Prob I now have is how to efficiently switch between buffers in different frames

I'm used to using `C-x o` to switch between buffers in a split frame on a single monitor but this doesn't work for multiple frames

Having to use the more cumbersome `C-x 5 b <buf-name>` which is painful in comparison

Anyone have any top-tips on how to make buffer switching more efficient across dual monitors?

Ideally I would like to cycle across all buffers using a single simple keyboard shortcut regardless of frames

Comment: what behavior, specifically, are you looking for?

Comment: do you just want `C-x o` to cycle across all visible buffers across all visible frames?  if so, i think you probably just want to bind that keybinding to `(other-window 0 'visible)`.

Comment: yes - i think thats exactly what i'm after, will give it a try

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd expect `C-x 5 o` to switch to the other frame, tho I don't have such a dual-screen setup to verify.

Comment: `C-x 5 o` also runs `other-frame`, so it's the same effect as my answer, with the pro of not requiring custom keybindings and the con of being a little cumbersome to type.

Answer (score 5):

With separate frames, I use the following to get mac osx style "same-app" switching with cmd-backtick. If you're on linux / windows you could do the same thing with alt-tilda:

```
(defined-key global-map (kbd "M-`") 'other-frame)
```

I like this because it keeps the action of switching frames separate from switching buffers.  With multiple screens, it's usually some kind of context switch when you want to change which one has focus.

Comment: holy crap i love this key binding set-up I had it set to C-x C-u near home row but with the window-numbering library it's really nice having M-1 through M-9 and to switch buffers and M-` to switch screens love it!

Answer (score 4):

Turning my comment above into an answer as it seems to be what the OP is after:

```
(defun other-window-visible ()
  (interactive)
  (other-window 0 'visible))
(global-set-key "\C-xo" 'other-window-visible)
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, but in trying found `next-multiframe-window` which seems spot on.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x o") 'next-multiframe-window)
```

(Though as spike mentioned, I think keeping `C-x o` bound to `other-window` and binding `next-multiframe-window` to something different makes sense.)

Comment: I bind this to M-o and it's great.